# Php - Ingres, fresh install : How to debug?

Tags: php, debian, ingres

I just finished to install Ingres on my server(only the client part, to connect to an existing ingres server), I just added the php_ingres module.

Now php recognize my module, so I tried to connect my self to several existing servers, but I always a

> Unable to connect to database (Hostname here)

But with this I can't find what is wrong?? ingres error? Php driver? Credentials? ...?

What can I do to isolate these problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's a user credentials issue. To see the actual error message use the following code:

```
$connection = ingres_connect(.....);
if (!is_resource($connection))
{
   trigger_error(ingres_errno()." - ". ingres_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

You might also want to take a look at http://community.ingres.com/wiki/Ingres_with_Apache_on_Debian_Etch which outlines the setup steps for Ingres, PHP, Apache and Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Great! Thank you! It will helps me a lot :)